# Erro ao formatar string para datetime python

Tags: python, datetime

Estou tentando formatar uma string com o formato `"2018-05-09T05:05:34Z"` para `"09/05/2018"`, mas está dado o erro:

> ValueError: unconverted data remains

Se eu usar:

```
dataAntiga = "2018-05-09T05:05:34Z"
datetime_object = parser.parse(dataAntiga)
dateTemp = datetime.strptime(str(datetime_object), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

O resultado é `2018-05-09 05:05:34+00:00` e dá o erro:

> ValueError: unconverted data remains: +00:00

Se eu usar direto o `data = datetime.strptime(dataAntiga, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')`, também vai dar o erro:

> ValueError: unconverted data remains

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<sup>*(Assumindo que você está usando `dateutil.parser`)*</sup>

Quando você chama [`parser.parse`](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parser.html#dateutil.parser.parse), o retorno (`datetime_object`) é uma variável do tipo [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects).

E este objeto pode ser formatado diretamente, através do método [`strftime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strftime). Neste método você passa o formato que quer (no caso, dia/mês/ano) e o retorno é uma string neste formato.

Então você poderia simplesmente fazer:

```
import dateutil.parser

dataAntiga = "2018-05-09T05:05:34Z"

# fazer o parse e obter um objeto datetime
datetime_object = dateutil.parser.parse(dataAntiga)

# formatar o datetime para o formato desejado (dia/mês/ano)
dataFormatada = datetime_object.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
print(dataFormatada)
```

A saída é:

> 09/05/2018

---

Como `parser.parse` retorna um `datetime`, **não tem porque convertê-lo para string (usando [`str`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-str)) para depois fazer o parse de novo com `strptime`**. Você já fez o parse uma vez (com `parser.parse`) e obteve um `datetime`, então basta formatá-lo para o formato que você quer, com `strftime`.

---

Outra alternativa é usar o método [`strptime`](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime)*****:

```
from datetime import datetime

dataAntiga = "2018-05-09T05:05:34Z"
# fazer o parse e obter um objeto datetime
datetime_object = datetime.strptime(dataAntiga, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z')

# formatar o datetime para o formato desejado (dia/mês/ano)
dataFormatada = datetime_object.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
print(dataFormatada) # 09/05/2018
```

*****: o `Z` no final indica que a data/hora [está em UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Coordinated_Universal_Time_(UTC)), mas infelizmente o *pattern* `%z` só reconhece o `Z` a partir do Python 3.7, conforme indicado na [documentação](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior):

> Changed in version 3.7: When the %z directive is provided to the strptime() method, ... providing 'Z' is identical to '+00:00'

Em versões anteriores, o `Z` não é reconhecido e dá erro. Nesse caso, o melhor é usar `dateutil` mesmo.

---

A [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/304174/112052) sugere usar `ignoretz=True`, mas como já vimos acima, não é necessário, pois `dateutil` consegue fazer o *parsing* corretamente sem este parâmetro.

Outro detalhe é que se usar `ignoretz=True`, o `datetime` retornado será *naive* (ou seja, não terá a informação do timezone - no caso, não saberá que a data e hora referem-se a UTC). E esta é uma informação importante, que pode fazer diferença dependendo de como você usar a data (neste caso específico não faz, mas é importante saber que há casos em que faz diferença, [leia a documentação](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#aware-and-naive-objects) para mais detalhes).

Comment: Obrigada, deu certo!

Answer (score 0):

Se não fizer diferença para você, acrescente o parâmetro `ignoretz=True` ao chamar o método `parse()`:

```
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil.parser import parse

data = parse("2018-05-09T05:05:34Z", ignoretz=True)

print datetime.strptime(str(data), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```